# Java trimming down code

Tags: java

I have a list of checkboxes that I would like to disable. Rather than typing

```
c1.setEnabled(false);
c2.setEnabled(false);
c3.setEnabled(false);
c4.setEnabled(false);
c5.setEnabled(false);
```

How could I trim this code down by putting them in some sort of group? I have the same issue throughout a lot of my code but with different components. Thanks

Comment: You could use an array for your items.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Java 8+, you could use a lambda like

```
Stream.of(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5).forEach(x -> x.setEnabled(false));
```

Comment: If I could this would be +1000. This is my favorite thing to use for this.

Answer (score 2):

Put them in a ArrayList or other collection of some sort.  Write a function that enables or does something to each element.  This is pretty useful for UIs where you have to do various actions on multiple components.